# Apache Commons FTP problems

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I want to implement a FTP Client with Apache Commons Net only for uploading data.
The Connection and Login to FTP-Server works fine.
But the upload does not work right.
The files are a little to big as the originals.
And the files are damaged.
I tried an image, a video and a textfile. Only the textfile is alright.

Now I see while debugging

```
boolean tmp=client.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

gives me `false`. So it can not be set. Why?
(Maybe this is not the problem?)

Here a the rest of my code

```
client=new FTPClient();

    try {           
        int reply;
        client.connect(url, port);
        reply = client.getReplyCode();

        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
        {
            client.disconnect();
            System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        client.login(user, pw);
        boolean xxx=client.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

if (client.isConnected())
    {
    try {
        File file=new File(<FILE>);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream outputStream = client.storeFileStream(file.getName());

          byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
          int l;
       while((l = inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1)
               {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, l);
            }

          inputStream.close();
          outputStream.flush();
          outputStream.close();}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the following:

```
boolean xxx=client.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Should be:

```
boolean xxx=client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

You have confused FileTransferModes with FileTypes.

The available FileTypes are:

- [FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#ASCII_FILE_TYPE)  (default)
- [FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
- [FTP.EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE)
- [FTP.LOCAL_FILE_TYPE](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#LOCAL_FILE_TYPE)

The available FileTransferModes are:

- [FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE)  (default)
- [FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE)
- [FTP.COMPRESSED_TRANSFER_MODE](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#COMPRESSED_TRANSFER_MODE)

I suppose if apache introduced enums for these constant types, then this kind of problem could be avoided, but then the library would not be available to pre-java-5 runtimes.
I wonder how much of an issue java 1.4 compatibility really is.

Answer (score 2):

If only the text file was transferred successfully, I suspect you need to set the binary transfer file type.

See the [setFileType](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType%28int%29) method to see how to do this.

The [commons-net wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Net/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) mentions this is the cause of most file corruption issues.

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but the method gives me false, so the Mode can not be set.

Comment: You tried this some where after the connect method was called?

Comment: And also after the login method.

Comment: He tried the `setFileTransferMode`, not the `setFileType` method you suggested. This is a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, Uploading Image and download after  It´s Ok: Using

```
    FTP.LOCAL_FILE_TYPE
```

this code using logger, replace for you logger or use System.out.println("");

```
    private void cargarData(File filelocal) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {

        client.connect("URLHOSTFTP", "PORT: DEFAULT 21");
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode())) {
            client.disconnect();
            logger.error("FTP server refused connection.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        client.login("USER FTP", "PASS FTP");
        boolean type = client.setFileType(FTP.LOCAL_FILE_TYPE);

        logger.info("Tipo Aceptado:" + type);
        client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        if (client.isConnected()) {
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            fis = new FileInputStream(filelocal);
            client.storeFile(filelocal.getName(), fis);
            client.logout();
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        logger.info(client.getReplyString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("error" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("error" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```