# apache commons ftp client file upload issue

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

I have few excel files locally on my machine. I want to upload this excel file to ftp. I m using apache commons FTPClinet. But when it uploads the file, it is corrupted and size of the is zero. Here is the sample program

Can anyone point me where am i doing wrong?

```
public class App {
    private static final String server = "localhost";
    private static final String username = "test";
    private static final String password = "test";
    private static final String directory = "/home/files";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
        f.connect(server);
        f.login(username, password);
        f.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        InputStream is = null;

        is = new FileInputStream("c:\\tmp\\output.xls");
        Boolean isStored = f.storeFile("status.xls", is);
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any error message, only problem is file is corrupted and not data being written

Comment: Can you post your error, please?

Comment: Are you sure `/home/files/status.txt` is valid in the context of the FTP server's directory structure?  That looks like an absolute path that may not be valid under the server's filestore root.

Comment: See the updated code which is now generating a excel file but still corrupted with some unreadable characters

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651158/apache-commons-ftp-problems?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `f.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` Remove that line.

Excel files are not binary, they should be transferred as ascii, which is the default for apache commons FTPClient I think.

I have't tested this. Give it a try.

Also change is from `InputStream` to `FileInputStream`

Comment: No Success my friend. This time i didnt see the unreadable content but I still see complete data in the copied file.

Comment: just making sure, in your code, the server name is not localhost, right?

Comment: and if it s linux server you are trying to upload it to, make sure the folder has sufficient privileges (777)

Comment: correct,i m using actual host name. And answer to roymustang86, i gave this persmission, so it is allowing to create file but it is corrupted

Comment: is it because excel file was created in windows os and then it copied via ftp client to linux, it is getting corrupted?

Comment: No, I don't think that is the cause. Try sending a normal .txt file via FTPClient and see if that gets corrupted too. Unlike xls file, you can do a `more test.txt` to check the contents to the file. If the text file is not getting corrupted, we can rule out that FTPClient is not responsible for the corruption.

Comment: Text files are working fine, no issues. It is csv and xls files are causing me an issue. Tried all possible solution recommended above, but no success.