# Java: upload a file to an FTP server

Tags: java, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to an FTP server

As I've found here [How do you upload a file to an FTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527664/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-an-ftp-server), I have this code:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    client.connect("IP");
    client.login("user", "pwd");
    client.changeWorkingDirectory("/a/b/c/");

    // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
    String filePath = file.getPath();
    fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    String fileName = file.getName();                               

    // Store file to server
    client.storeFile(fileName, fis);
    client.logout();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
    if (fis != null) {
        fis.close();
    }
    client.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run it, the file is created where expected, but it is empty (0 kb)

The writing process also takes quite a lot of time...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Find if this piece of code is good: String filePath = file.getPath();
    fis = new FileInputStream(filePath); how do you create file object? It's may be slow because your internet connection is slow or your ftp server is slow... may be

Comment: Any error/exception?

Comment: Can you upload the same file to the same server and directory using a standalone FTP client?

Comment: I have added  System.out.println(file.length());  and the file i'm trying to transfer isn't empty (991b). It's a simple .txt file. No errors or exceptions. I can move the file to that location with FileZilla witohout problems

Comment: As I hav found here java FTP upload creates empty file (the answer by JK Patel), adding client.enterLocalPassiveMode(); resolved my problem

Answer (score -1):

Look at this post
[Apache Commons FTP problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651158/apache-commons-ftp-problems)
You need to set file type and tranfor mode to make this work.

Comment: What make you think that a wrong transfer mode can cause the uploaded file to be empty?

Comment: I have added file type (BINARY_FILE_TYPE) and trasfer mode (STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE), but the problem remains